# Calling jsonp type ajax returns json in firebug but triggers error in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

As title says I had **jsonp cross domain ajax query**. it returns json list and i **can monitor it from firebug** but at jquery ajax function **error:** part is working despite error status 200 OK, and status text success.

I have no access to remote server so I can't configure CORS. Remote server just provides webservice that returns json list.

--my ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: "url/for/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",        
    success: function(data, success){
        console.log(" success ");
    },
    error: function(error){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        },
});
```

--response in firebug

[image: firebug screenshot]

--And alert called inside error part (no code runned inside success)

[image]

Returned json is valid I tested.

**I can monitor all my json data in firebug and everything ok there but I can't access data inside browser(javascript). I tried almost everything I found in web all day but no help. Is there a way to access data in response**

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: "url/for/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",        
    success: function(data, success){
        console.log(" success ");
        console.log(data)  //  here you will have access to the response.
    },
    error: function(error){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        },
});
```

In success callback, you will have access to the returned data.

Comment: I tried that. but any code inside success part is not compiled ie. ajax directly calls error part.